# Can we have multiple key values in same column?

Tags: mysql, database

A student may be a different game player. Assume studentA playing, cricket, carrom board, athlet. For this I have master table like table (game_id (pk), game_name (varchar(300)).

In student information table contains student details. Now i need to store the game id which are applicable for that student. For this, how can i store game id in a student info  table, if one student plays more than one game.

Comment: read about normalization, one-to-many and many-to-one relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I know is to create a separate table filles with foreign key, let's say "Student_sports" with records like

```
student_id           sport_id
  1                     1
  1                     2
  2                     2
  3                     1
```